# `@` symbol in string causes unexpected results

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

It seems that, when the `@` symbol is paired with a `#` symbol is starts ignoring certain characters. It even does this inside the `%{}` delimiter. What is going on here?

```
"1#@ #9"
#=> "1\#@ #9"
"1#@X#9"
#=> "1#9"
"1#@XXX#9"
#=> "1#9"
"1#@X123#9"
#=> "1#9"
"1#\@X123#9"
#=> "1\#@X123#9"
"#"
#=> "#"
"@"
#=> "@"
"\@"
#=> "@"
"@XX"
#=> "@XX"
"1@XX1"
#=> "1@XX1"
"#@XX#"
#=> "#"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@` is a sigil for instance variables in Ruby, and when it follows `#`, which indicates interpolation, interpolation happens. In your examples, instance variables `@X` and `@XX` are called, which I suppose are not defined. If so, then these variables are `nil` by default, which expands to empty strings by `to_s` for interpolation. When `#@` cannot be interpreted as interpolation (for example `@` is invalid instance variable name), then it is recognized as `#@` verbatim, and escape characters are inserted in the inspection.

Comment: Icky, why is it doing this when I use the `%{}` delimiter though, shouldn't it produce a literal string (ignoring the special interpolation, `"` and `'`)? Is there someway I can make it not do this?

Comment: No. `%{}` is string literal with interpolation.

Comment: Is there some way to make this not interpolate or do I just need to change the `#` and `@` symbols here to prevent this?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes, or escape at least either of `#` or `@`.

Comment: Alright will do! Thanks for the help, one last question, is there some way to stop this when using the `%{}` (or a similar delimiter). Befunge uses a 2d playfield to process instructions and I like using `%{}` to make the grid easier to read.

Comment: Use `%q{}`. This is for non-interpolated string.

Comment: Thanks! Trying to figure out why my befunge programs were going into the infinite was killing me.